# Use of "at most"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "a 28.9 % decrease, a 63.37% increase and 72.8% increase" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> At most, a 28.9 % decrease in the global entropy generation rate, a
>   63.37% increase in torque coefficient and 72.8% increase in efficiency are achieved by the VTB in the deep stall condition.

Comment: I would suggest you say "...and **a** 72.8% increase..." to not violate parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence seems perfectly grammatical and meaningful to me. It appears to pertain to mechanical engineering, a field in which I am not an expert, so I can't tell you if that is how a mechanical engineer would express those ideas, but I'd be surprised if it were considered incorrect.

One thing I should mention is that the phrase "at most" has to apply to all three changes for the sentence to be correct. It applies to the magnitude of the numbers 28.9, 63.37, and 72.8, not their direction (increase/decrease).

Comment: +1 good point in the second paragraph. If the OP wants the *at most* modifier to be assigned to only one of the three figures, then the position of the term has to be different.